# .exe file opening Powershell Window

Tags: python, powershell, pyinstaller, exe

I made an .exe file using pyinstaller, but when I run the file it opens a PowerShell window as well. I was wondering if there is anyway I can get it to not open so I just have the python program open.

I haven't really tried anything as I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running pyinstaller be sure to use the --windowed argument. For example:

> pyinstaller –-onefile myFile.py –-windowed

Answer (score 0):

if you run it from terminal, you can use this command:

start /min "" "path\file_name.exe"